# Laravel 5 crear Tabla y modelo AutoReferenciada (self Referencing)

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

¿Cómo creo un tabla `autor` referenciada y como hago la relación en el modelo de la misma?:

Ejemplo:

```
Tengo una tabla: Categoria
Campos: categoria_id, nombre, categoria_padre
```

Se traduce que una **categoria** (padre) puede tener muchas **sub-categorias** (hijas) haciendo la referencia en el campo **categoria_padre**

Answer (score 1):

Realmente es muy sencillo en Laravel, simplemente defines las relaciones en el mismo modelo, con su respectiva llave foránea:

```
public function hijas()
{
    return $this->hasMany('Categoria', 'categoria_padre');
}

public function padre()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('Categoria', 'categoria_padre');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Si, es sencillo y para operaciones mas avanzadas te recomiendo el paquete [Baum](https://github.com/etrepat/baum), puedes obtener todos los descendientes de un nodo en una sola consulta, sin importar cuán profundo sea el árbol.

```
class Catalog extends Node
{
    protected $fillable = [
        'name',
        'parent_id',
        'left',
        'right',
        'depth'
    ];
}
```

y ya incluye las relaciones que necesitas:

```
public function parent()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(Catalog::class, 'parent_id');
}

public function children()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Catalog::class, 'parent_id');
}
```

entre otras:

```
ancestorsAndSelf()
ancestors()
siblingsAndSelf()
siblings()
leaves()
descendantsAndSelf()
descendants()
immediateDescendants()
```